# Simplify a rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Suppose I want to simplify this expression:
$$\frac{bx-bc-dx+ad}{a-c}$$
More specifically, I want to minimize the number of operations. Counting each addition, subtraction, and multiplication, the expression requires 9 operations to compute.

The expression $$b+\frac{(x-a)(b-d)}{a-c}$$ is equivalent to the previous expression, yet requires only 6 operations to compute.

So, my real question is, starting with the top expression, how do I derive the bottom expression? I want to know step-by-step. I can't think of any factoring techniques that would help me here. I know how to go from the bottom expression to the top expression, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{bx-bc-dx+ad}{a-c}&=\frac{x(b-d)+ad-ab+ab-bc}{a-c}\\
&=\frac{x(b-d)-a(b-d)+b(a-c)}{a-c}\\
&=\frac{(x-a)(b-d)+b(a-c)}{a-c}\\
&=\frac{b(a-c)}{a-c}+\frac{(x-a)(b-d)}{a-c}\\
&=b+\frac{(x-a)(b-d)}{a-c}\\
\end{align}

Comment: How did you know that introducing `-ab + ab` would help you factor?

Comment: we had $ad$, adding $-ab$ leaves us with $d-b$, and this might have helped, so I tried.